# How to refer to the file currently being loaded in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am looking to include a reference to a non-elisp file (a small Python program), and would like to be able to say "it is in the same directory as the current file, but with a different file name." In many scripting languages, there are things like `__FILE__` (in PHP) for getting an absolute path to the current file.

If the file to be included is in the `load-path`, then I can find it with `(locate-library "file.py" t)`, but I'm kind of stuck if the file is not in the load path.

So is there a way for an Emacs Lisp file to find out its own absolute path (when being loaded, not visited)?

Comment: Changed the title to reflect the question asked. The original title to the question would lead me to want to answer "the variable `buffer-file-name`" which isn't what you asked.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`M-x describe-variable load-file-name`

```
load-file-name is a variable defined in `C source code'.

Documentation:
Full name of file being loaded by `load'.
```

You might also be interested in the `symbol-file` function, which will tell you the absolute filename in which a specified function or variable was defined.

If you want to get fancy, you can check the `load-in-progress` variable.  If that's `nil`, then no load is in progress (and you're presumably being `eval`'d in a buffer).  In that case, you could try `(buffer-file-name)` to get the filename.

Comment: Simpler fancyness: `(or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))`

Comment: Upvote for `symbol-file`, for allowing self-referential code.  Currently using a variant on `(defvar my-locn nil) (setq my-locn (symbol-file 'my-locn))`.