# elisp: Is there a way to get the name of the current .el module (like __FILE__ in C)?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

At the top of my elisp module, I want to do something as simple as:

```
(message (concat "Loading " (expand-file-name (current-elisp-module) ".")))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refer to the file currently being loaded in Emacs Lisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344747/how-to-refer-to-the-file-currently-being-loaded-in-emacs-lisp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the variable [`load-file-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html#index-load_002dfile_002dname), which is set by the function [`load`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html#index-load), documented as follows:

> Full name of file being loaded by `load'.

As elaborated in the manual:

> When Emacs is in the process of loading a file, this variable’s value is the name of that file, as Emacs found it during the search described earlier in this section.

*Note:* [`buffer-file-name`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html) as a routine does not work as you might expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for rounding out the answer, Trey. I was more hurried than usual writing that, and figured it would be helpful to put it out sooner than later.