# How to modularize an emacs configuration?

Tags: configuration, emacs, elisp

I've decided to rewrite my .emacs from the ground up, and I want to setup something that's modular, in order to avoid a dreaded 1k+ LoC init.el file...

I think there are some basic concerns that each configuration needs to address :

- global options
- editing functions
- navigation (frames & buffers)
- keybindings
- modes customizations

While I'm still tying to think the structure through, I'm looking for some pointers on how to achieve this.
I've looked at some .emacs on github and such, and there seems to be deifferent approaches, and no preferred way to go with this, which is a bit confusing.
I would be interested in reading some ideas regarding how to structure such a setup, and especially some related elisp code.

---

edit : Been caught up with things, and haven't had much time to play with this yet.
Will try out the proposed methods in a few days, and see what's best, meanwhile thanks for all the recommendations !

---

edit2 : I've been using a [literate init file with org-mode](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.php#literate-programming), and this is absolutely terrific !
I 'm not yet set on a specific load mechanism, I've been using this code, to recursively load my elisp directory, then require or whatever the setup instructions say.

```
  (if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
  (let* ((my-lisp-dir "~/.emacs.d/elisp/")
  (default-directory my-lisp-dir))
  (setq load-path (cons my-lisp-dir load-path))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)))
```

I still need to polish this, maybe using autoload, and some byte-recompile if modified tricks ; would love to hear suggestions on that.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

My *.emacs* file loads *~/.emacs.d/init.el*, which defines the following functions, written first for XEmacs, but working well enough for Emacs these days:

```
(defconst user-init-dir
  (cond ((boundp 'user-emacs-directory)
         user-emacs-directory)
        ((boundp 'user-init-directory)
         user-init-directory)
        (t "~/.emacs.d/")))


(defun load-user-file (file)
  (interactive "f")
  "Load a file in current user's configuration directory"
  (load-file (expand-file-name file user-init-dir)))
```

Then the rest of the file goes and loads lots of individual files with forms like this:

```
(load-user-file "personal.el")
```

My current set of files is as follows:

- personal.el
- platform.el
- cygwin.el
- variables.el
- paths.el
- mail-news.el
- misc-funcs.el
- bbdb.el
- calendar.el
- gnus-funcs.el
- c-and-java.el
- lisp.el
- clojure.el
- go.el
- markdown.el
- sgml-xml.el
- tex.el
- spelling.el
- org.el
- packages.el
- fonts.el
- color-theme.el
- frame.el
- server.el
- keys.el
- aquamacs.el

Some of them are much more specific in intent than others, as the names suggest. The more fine-grained the files, the easier it is to disable a cluster of forms when you're reinstalling a package or library. This is especially useful when "moving in" to a new system, where you drag your configuration files over but don't yet have all the supporting packages installed.

Comment: Just what I was aiming at. Nice.

Comment: That is why I tend to have the supporting packages tucked away somewhere in my .emacs folder.

Comment: Wouldn't the file name conflicting with real package? Or you are loading the full path instead of simple require?

Comment: Note the call to `load-file` shown above: it supplies a path formed from file base name within `user-init-dir`. That is, rather than trying to load the first file called _markdown.el_ from the `load-path`, it will specifically load the file _/home/myusername/.emacs.d/markdown.el_.

Comment: Tonight I discovered Aaron Bedra's clever use of *org-mode* to define his configuration as a "literate program": https://github.com/abedra/emacs.d. See the exported org-as-HTML documentation here: http://www.aaronbedra.com/emacs.d/. I am inspired to try changing my configuration approach to use one file like this, though I'd lose the more precise version control tracking when I change just a few related things in one of the files listed above. Is the ability to write documentation worth inverting the normal documentation-inside-code arrangement?

Answer (score 7):

You can do `(require 'foo)` and that will load the first "foo.el" elisp finds in your load path, or `(require 'foo "/home/user/experimental/foo.el")` for something outside your load path. It will report an error if "foo.el" does not contain the expression `(provide 'foo)`. In a perverse situation you could do `(require 'foo "bar.el")`, and this would work as long as "bar.el" had a `(provide 'foo)` clause.

Answer (score 6):

To split customizations into different files, you can use [initsplit.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitSplit).  Also, the wiki has a page on [modular .emacs layout](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsModular).

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using `load-file`?

Some additional bits you might find useful include

- `file-exists-p`
- `file-expand-wildcards`

Use `C-h f <function>` to get help, and you might find [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1882114566) useful (or [download the PDF](http://www.ie.gnu.org/doc/Intro-Elisp-Review1.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split up your `custom-set-variables`, but want
something lighter weight than `initsplit.el`, then try this:

```
(defmacro custom-set-variable (var value)
  "Call `custom-set-variables' with a warning shown
when customizing using the customize GUI.

XXX: does not support setting the optional NOW and
REQUEST (dependency) fields."
  (custom-set-variables
    ;; `load-file-name' is set by `load-file':
    ;; http://stackoverflow.com/a/1971376/470844
    `(,var ,value nil nil
      ,(format "!!! CAREFUL: CUSTOM-SET IN %s !!!" load-file-name))))
```

Now, put your configuration modules in separate files, and load them
with `load-file` in your `~/.emacs`, as others have suggested.  In each
configuration module, use

```
(custom-set-variable var value)
```

instead of

```
(custom-set-variables '(var value))
```

or

```
(setq-default var value)
```

when setting variables managed by customize.  Then, if you ever need
to customize the variable using the customize interface, you'll see a
warning telling you which file the customization should be stored in:

```
"!!! CAREFUL: CUSTOM-SET IN <path to module file> !!!"
```

If you version control your config files, then a diff will tell which
line of your `~/.emacs` to move into the custom module.

Discussion of issues with naively using multiple
`custom-set-variables` calls: http://www.dotemacs.de/custbuffer.html

## Edit: Response to Alan's questions

### The problem the `custom-set-variable` macro above solves

The customize interface in Emacs saves all custom set variables in
your `~/.emacs` whenever you edit any custom set variable. If you
modularize your custom-set variables, by spreading them across
multiple files, then you need to realize when emacs inserts duplicate
settings in your .emacs, and remove them.  The `custom-set-variable`
macro above helps you do this.

### A real example from my config files

I custom-set variables related to whitespace in a
`~/.emacs.d/extensions/whitespace.el` file that gets loaded by my
[`~/.emacs`](http://code.google.com/p/nathan-collins--conf/source/browse/dot.emacs#97).  For example, I set my [`search-whitespace-regexp`](http://code.google.com/p/nathan-collins--conf/source/browse/dot.emacs.d/extensions/whitespace.el#56)
variable like this:

```
(nc:custom-set-variable search-whitespace-regexp "[ \t\r\n]+")
```

Now, two things happen.  First, when I come across that variable in
the customization interface I get a warning:

[image: Generated warning in Emacs' customization dialog]

Second, if I edit any variables using the customization interface, my
`~/.emacs` makes it very obvious that I've shadowed some definitions.
For example, after changing `search-whitespace-regexp` and
`global-whitespace-mode` in the customization interface, I get:

```
$ svn di --diff-cmd "diff" -x "-U0" ~/v/conf
Index: /home/collins/v/conf/dot.emacs
===================================================================
--- /home/collins/v/conf/dot.emacs  (revision 267)
+++ /home/collins/v/conf/dot.emacs  (working copy)
@@ -55,0 +56 @@
+ '(agda2-include-dirs (\` ("." (\, (file-truename "~/local/opt/agda-std-lib/src")))) nil nil "!!! CAREFUL: CUSTOM-SET IN /home/collins/.emacs.d/extensions/agda.el !!!")
@@ -58,0 +60,3 @@
+ '(global-whitespace-mode t)
+ '(indent-tabs-mode nil nil nil "!!! CAREFUL: CUSTOM-SET IN /home/collins/.emacs.d/extensions/whitespace.el !!!")
+ '(indicate-empty-lines t nil nil "!!! CAREFUL: CUSTOM-SET IN /home/collins/.emacs.d/extensions/whitespace.el !!!")
@@ -72,0 +77 @@
+ '(search-whitespace-regexp "" nil nil "!!! CAREFUL: CUSTOM-SET IN /home/collins/.emacs.d/extensions/whitespace.el !!!")
@@ -74,0 +80 @@
+ '(tab-width 2 nil nil "!!! CAREFUL: CUSTOM-SET IN /home/collins/.emacs.d/extensions/whitespace.el !!!")
```

The macro doesn't help me remember that I changed
`search-whitespace-regexp`, only that it's already set somewhere else,
but it does help me know which variable settings I should remove from
my `~/.emacs` (all those with warnings), and which ones I should leave
in my `~/.emacs`, or move to other separate files (all those without
warnings).

### Conclusion

The macro is probably overkill, but once it exists it's easy to use, and makes it
easier to avoid shooting yourself in the foot with shadowed custom set
variables.

Comment: So what use does the customize interface play once you have this code in place? Are you supposed to save your changes via the interface, then transfer the resulting changes in your .emacs file into your custom file, removing them from your .emacs file?

Comment: Also, I suppose you're saying that you're going to change something like this: 

    (custom-set-variables
      '(column-number-mode t)
      '(display-time-mode t))

to this:


    (custom-set-variable column-number-mode t)
    (custom-set-variable display-time-mode t)

Is that right?

Comment: @Alan: see new examples above.  The main use is to help you avoid accidentally setting variables twice, in two different files, when using the customize interface.  You can make the changes via the interface or directly in the config files, but in practice I find the interface more friendly, e.g. when I don't know what the variable I change to change is called, and so I'm browsing in customize.  And yes, I use it just like you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear and explicit explanation. I understand how it works now.

Comment: The point about changing *any* option via customize UI, results in *all* programmatically set custom options (with `custom-set-variables`) being duplicated in the nominated custom file is key - I also labour the point in perhaps too much detail here, going through a step-by-step demonstration of the difference of `setq` vs `custom-set-variables` if it helps people: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55018/init-el-and-trampling-of-custom-set-variables?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the excellent [emacs starter kit](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) which is very nicely organised and also includes ELPA packages. I used the structure as inspiration for my own much simpler setup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a library which allows you to install new modules simply by saving them in a designated directory.  It can be downloaded and installed from http://github.com/tripleee/my-site-start/

```
    ;;; my-site-start.el --- set up personal .emacs.d/site-start.d/
    ;;
    ;; Copyright (C) era eriksson <http://www.iki.fi/~era/> 2008-2009
    ;; License: GPL v2
    ;; Version: see `my-site-start-version' below
    ;;
    ;;; Commentary:
    ;;
    ;; The purpose of my-site-start is to simplify maintenance of user libraries.
    ;; Instead of indefinitely tweaking your .emacs, just create a site-start.d
    ;; directory and add symlinks to the libraries you want to load into Emacs.
```

This architecture does impose some conventions which you might or might not like.  See the rest of the commentary section near the top of the file for the full scoop.

I am the author of this code, and appreciate any feedback (though not directly via this public forum).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JoeCasadonte for mentioning the [EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsModular). As I'm using Debian and Ubuntu, this particular snippet from it worked just well (to be put in .emacs.d/init.el):

```
(setq dotfiles-dir (file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))))

(let ((user-site-start-dir (concat dotfiles-dir "/site-start.d")))
    (debian-run-directories user-site-start-dir))
```

Then, I just need to put my .el files inside ~/.emacs.d/site-start.d (e.g. `~/.emacs.d/site-start.d/50cedet.el`) and they all get loaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is for each thing, X, that I might want to use, create a file called configure-X, and put a corresponding `require` in .emacs. This feature can then be removed by commenting out one line.

For example, to pick the simplest (if most poorly-named), I have configure-picture-and-artist-mode.el. This file is very simple:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-P")
                'picture-mode)

(provide 'configure-picture-and-artist-mode)
```

And in .emacs:

```
(require 'configure-picture-and-artist-mode)
```

After sorting this out I don't have anything in my .emacs except for a big list of `require`s and a few changes to `load-path`, a given package can be removed quite easily, and all the configuration for each package is in one place.

(I've also got a catch-all .el file that I use to store things that don't have any obvious home (my global keybindings, helper functions, etc.) but still ideally want to stay out of .emacs. This bit isn't very modular, and may introduce implicit dependencies on packages that my scheme is supposed to make unloadable easily, but in practice it doesn't seem to be a big deal.)

Comment: Can you share more of how you coax 'require' to find the files that contain the 'provide' forms? Do you specify a file name for `require`'s second argument?

Comment: @seh you don't need to as long as the 'provided' file is in the load-path. I could have a file foo.el, within which I have (provide 'foo) or (provide 'foobar) or whatever, then in my init file I can say (require 'foo) (or foobar or whatever) and it'll load the file.

Comment: I named each file after the symbol provided, made sure the containing folder is in load-path... and it just worked. (I'm not sure of the detailed ins and outs of this mechanism, but I suspect that require just knows to try to load a file named after the symbol if no loaded file has already provided the requested symbol. Anyway this is just what I'd noticed other elisp files doing, so I copied it.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to experiment with setting this up in my own configuration files today.

Comment: See `C-h f require RET` for details of how that mechanism works. Also notice the `NOERROR` argument, which facilitates conditional behaviour depending on whether or not the feature in question could be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `init-loader.el`, is a loader of configuration files. `init-loader.el` loads configuration files from specified directory. It enables you to categorize your configurations and separate them into multiple files.

[Fore more info, please visit init-loader GitHub Repo](https://github.com/emacs-jp/init-loader)