# Get path to current emacs script file when loaded with -l parameter

Tags: emacs, elisp

From within a lisp file being loaded and run with `emacs -l path/to/script/foo.el` can I get the path to file being run?

For example, is there some way to determine what `path/to/script` is from within `foo.el`?

I am not very experienced with lisp so please be gentle with your solutions.

Emacs 22.3.1 on Windows 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refer to the file currently being loaded in Emacs Lisp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344747/how-to-refer-to-the-file-currently-being-loaded-in-emacs-lisp)

Comment: @Trey Jackson, I agree that it is close but it would have taken me a little more time to track down the file-name-directory function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The variable `load-file-name` is bound to the name of the file as it is being loaded.  To get the directory, you'd just use `file-name-directory`, like so:

```
(file-name-directory load-file-name)
```

Comment: @JesseVogt Not so *perfect* ; `eval` it in a `require`d package file: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  file-name-directory(nil)
`

Comment: @yPhil The call to `file-name-directory` requires a string be passed in, you apparently called it with a `nil`.  The variable is only set during a call to `load` - which is the context of the question.